# using Tensorflow 2.x.x and running into error with unused arugments

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, pde

Essentially I am trying to illustrate the efficiency of a method on solving high-dimensional fully nonlinear second-order PDE's in the case of a 100-dimensional HJB (Hamilton-Jacobi-Bellman equation). I keep running into this error. It is found within the _one_layer funcion where w and b are defined:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#199>", line 23, in <module>
    Gamma = tf.reshape(_one_time_net(X, name=str(i)+'Gamma', isgamma=True)/d**2, [batch_size , d, d])
  File "<pyshell#197>", line 3, in _one_time_net
    layer1 = _one_layer(x, (1-isgamma )* n_neuronForA [1] / +isgamma*n_neuronForGamma [1], name = 'layer1')
  File "<pyshell#195>", line 5, in _one_layer
    w = tf.compat.v1.get_variable_scope('Matrix', [shape [1], output_size], tf.float64, tf.random_normal_initializer(stddev=stddev/np.sqrt(shape [1]+ output_size )))
TypeError: get_variable_scope() takes 0 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

## My Full Code

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import time, datetime

d = 20
T = 0.3
Xi = np.zeros([1,d])

# setup of algorithm and implementation
N = 20
h = T/N
sqrth = np.sqrt(h)
n_maxstep = 10000
batch_size = 1
gamma = 0.001

# neural net architectures
n_neuronForGamma = [d, d, d, d**2]
n_neuronForA = [d, d, d, d]

# (adapted) rhs of the pde
def f0(t,X,Y,Z,Gamma):
    return -Y+tf.pow(Y, 3)

# terminal condition
def g(X):
    return 1/(1 + 0.2*tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(X), 1, keep_dims=True ))*0.5

# helper functions for constructing the neural net(s)
def _one_layer(input_ , output_size , activation_fn=tf.nn.relu, stddev =5.0, name='linear'):
    with tf.compat.v1.variable_scope(name):
        shape = input_.get_shape().as_list()
        w = tf.compat.v1.get_variable_scope('Matrix', [shape [1], output_size], tf.float64, tf.random_normal_initializer(stddev=stddev/np.sqrt(shape [1]+ output_size )))
        b = tf.compat.v1.get_variable_scope('Bias', [1, output_size], tf.float64, tf.constant_initializer (0.0))
        hidden = tf.matmul(input_ , w) + b
        if activation_fn:
            return activation_fn(hidden)
        else:
            return hidden

def _one_time_net(x, name , isgamma = False):
    with tf.compat.v1.variable_scope(name):
        layer1 = _one_layer(x, (1-isgamma )* n_neuronForA [1] / +isgamma*n_neuronForGamma [1], name = 'layer1')
        layer2 = _one_layer(layer1 , (1-isgamma )* n_neuronForA [2] / +isgamma*n_neuronForGamma [2], name = 'layer2')
        z = _one_layer(layer2 , (1-isgamma )* n_neuronForA [3] / +isgamma*n_neuronForGamma [3], activation_fn=None , name = 'final')
        return z

with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    # background dynamics
    dW = tf.random.normal(shape=[ batch_size , d], stddev = sqrth, dtype=tf.float64)

    # initial values of the stochastic processes
    X = tf.Variable(np.ones([batch_size , d]) * Xi, dtype = tf.float64, name = 'X', trainable = False)
    Y0 = tf.Variable(tf.random.uniform ([1], minval = -1, maxval = 1, dtype=tf.float64), name = 'Y0')
    Z0 = tf.Variable(tf.random.uniform ([1,d], minval = -.1, maxval = .1, dtype=tf.float64), name = 'Z0')
    Gamma0 = tf.Variable(tf.random.uniform ([d, d], minval = -.1, maxval = .1, dtype=tf.float64), name = 'Gamma0')
    A0 = tf.Variable(tf.random.uniform ([1,d], minval = -.1, maxval = .1, dtype=tf.float64), name = 'A0')
    allones = tf.ones(shape=[batch_size, 1], dtype=tf.float64 , name='MatrixOfOnes')
    Y = allones * Y0
    Z = tf.matmul(allones, Z0)
    Gamma = tf.multiply(tf.ones([batch_size , d, d], dtype = tf.float64), Gamma0)
    A = tf.matmul(allones, A0)

    # forward discretization
    with tf.compat.v1.variable_scope('forward'):
        for i in range(N-1):
            Y = Y + f0(i*h,X,Y,Z,Gamma )*h + tf.reduce_sum(dW*Z, 1, keepdims=True)

            Z = Z + A * h + tf.squeeze(tf.matmul(Gamma, tf.expand_dims(dW , -1)))
            Gamma = tf.reshape(_one_time_net(X, name=str(i)+'Gamma', isgamma=True)/d**2, [batch_size , d, d])
            if i!=N-1:
                A = _one_time_net(X, name=str(i)+'A')/d
            X = X + dW
            dW = tf.random.normal(shape=[batch_size, d], stddev = sqrth, dtype=tf.float64)

        Y = Y + f0( (N-1)*h , X,Y,Z,Gamma )*h + tf.reduce_sum(dW*Z, 1, keep_dims=True)
        X = X + dW
        loss_function = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(Y-g(X)))

# specifying the optimizer
    global_step = tf.compat.v1.get_variable_scope('global_step', [], initializer = tf.constant_initializer (0), trainable = False , dtype=tf.int32)

    learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(gamma, global_step, decay_steps = 10000, decay_rate = 0.0, staircase = True)

    trainable_variables = tf.trainable_variables()
    grads = tf.gradients(loss_function, trainable_variables)
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)
    apply_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads , trainable_variables), global_step=global_step , name='train_step')

    with tf.control_dependencies ([apply_op]):
        train_op_2 = tf.identity(loss_function , name='train_op2')

    # to save history
    learning_rates = []
    y0_values = []
    losses = []
    running_time = []
    steps = []
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    try:
        # the actual training loop
        for _ in range(n_maxstep + 1):
            y0_value, step = sess.run([Y0, global_step])
            currentLoss, currentLearningRate = sess.run([train_op_2, learning_rate])

            learning_rates.append(currentLearningRate)
            losses.append(currentLoss)
            y0_values.append(y0_value)
            running_time.append(time.time() - start_time)
            steps.append(step)

            if step % 100 == 0:
                print("step: ", step, "loss: ", currentLoss, "Y0: ", y0_value, "learning rate: ", currentLearningRate)

        end_time = time.time()
        print("running time: ", end_time - start_time)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("\nmanually disengaged")
```

Any suggestions or help?

Comment: The error is very clear. `get_variable_scope` takes no arguments, but you are giving it multiple.

Comment: I know the meaning of the error, but im unsure how to make the right changes

Comment: Did you mean to use `tf.compat.v1.get_variable`?